# Spinner toasts item name when clicked, instead of numeric value of the item

Tags: android, android-spinner

I made a Spinner and every time I click on the item it toasts the item name.
 But instead I want to toast the numeric value of the item.
This is my main.java file.

```
    Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
    private Button btnSubmit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
    }

    // add items into spinner dynamically
    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    }
}
```

This is my CustomOnItemSelectedListener.java file.

```
    package com.dev.app.dropdown;

    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements     AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                "OnItemSelectedListener:" +     parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check my answer below ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Spinner MySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                Integer indexValue = MySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Toast.makeText(EditPlanActivity.this, "value" + indexValue + " pos " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: It's better to change the object name `Spinner MySpinner` to `Spinner mySpinner`. Currently it's ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()
```

use

```
Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

**Full code :**

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

  String selectItem = Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
  Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                "OnItemSelectedListener:" +  selectItem,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```